# Android - Can I make an app think I'm in a different country?

Tags: android

I have a downloaded app which works only in **poland**, and recently had to move to the **usa** for a short period of time.

I would like to run the application here but am getting the "video can only be played in poland" message.

Is there any way I could make the app think I am in my country?

Comment: Will you be running this app while on cellular or wifi?

Comment: @SamusArin Wifi

Comment: google 'circumventing geoblocking'

Comment: Try setting your router's DHCP range to start at one of these major IP address blocks allocated for Poland http://www.nirsoft.net/countryip/pl.html.

Comment: @SamusArin I'm very new in this. Could you please tell me how to do it? The router is served by AT&T brand: Arris

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a VPN. Many offer free data plans (OperaVPN, Tunnelbear, Windscribe, etc...)

Answer (score 0):

Under settings, make sure Developer options are enabled (if not, go into About and keep clicking Build number until it unlocks them).

Under Developer options, use Set mock location app to specify an app for setting your location.

Comment: This particular check is more likely using geoip checks than gps checks.

Comment: This will not work, as the application this OP is referring to is most certainly checking the IP location, not the GPS data.

Comment: Good to know...